# I can't find the apache http server msi installer

Tags: apache, httpserver

I really can't find the apache http server msi. All links lead to this page: http://download.nextag.com/apache//httpd/binaries/win32/ and when I use their mirror site still no .msi. Where can i find the latest version of apache http server msi? Thank you to all!

Comment: Why not just compile it? http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/platform/win_compiling.html

Comment: Its much harder. Just the easy installation.

Comment: It's questions like this that makes me wish Stack Overflow allowed let me google that for you links.

Answer (score 9):

The last version of apache is no more available as msi. However, you may found it up to version 2.2.x in the archive:
http://archive.apache.org/dist/httpd/binaries/win32/

Answer (score 5):

.msi Not available for 2.4X .

you need first to install your edition from here : 
http://httpd.apache.org/download.cgi

make sure you are installed VC .
you can find VC from here : 
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145

after unzip where you unzipped ( best in C drive )
go to bin folder from : C:\Apache24\bin
and open : ApacheMonitor.exe 
after run click on start ( you find icon on start menu bar ) 
and you get it.

Answer (score 4):

You will not find it! i have tried to find it myself. that's the "old" way of downloading Apache. here is where you have to go to download Apache web server.

http://www.apachelounge.com/

Answer (score 1):

The binaries available from Apache Haus and other places are actually quite easy to work with. You just download the zip and then extract the folder within to your program files folder. The readme has some additional information on starting the server. I got an error when I first tried to start it: "ServerRoot" is not a valid directory". That's because I needed to go into the httpd.conf and edit the ServerRoot line to point to C:/program files/Apache24